# Is it possible to create a LinkedIn test user?

Tags: linkedin-api

This question was answered many years ago but things appear to have changed.

You need to do SMS and government ID verification to create a LinkedIn account now. However in LinkedIn's documentation it states that we can create 5 test users.

How is it possible to create test users with these restrictions?

Comment: I'd ask  linkedin support about this.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Their documentation says to go on StackOverflow and tag LinkedIn for support

Comment: Well, let's hope some linked staff shows up here then.

Comment: I guess this is why so few sites use linkedin for authentication